# DriveEye only sends errors even after disabling it

Tags: google-apps-script

I have added the DriveEye app to my Chrome, and enabled it to see my account. It is used for sending automated e-mail alerts on Google Drive shared folder activity.
It is not working. I receive only error messages ( I can not include it here as it is in Hungarian). It is about server error.
Then I removed the DriveEye from Chrome (drag and drop in the Chrome start screen). Nothing changed. I still receive errors.
How can I ged rid of it? How can I remove it completely or take the authorization back?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I had the same symptoms.

There doesn't seem any way to remove DriveEye, but I found a way to delete its triggers, which stops the error emails.

Overview:  The web-based authoring environment for Google Apps Script contains a menu item "Resources --> All Your Triggers".  You can manage your Triggers here.  (It appears to be the only place you can do this.)

Trick #1:  Due to an apparent masking bug, you can't access this menu item unless you have at least one active script, and it is currently open.  A completely empty dummy script will suffice.

Trick #2:  Deleting the trigger(s) won't occur right away.  You must preserve the script which you used to delete the triggers for an unknown amount of time. Might as well keep it indefinitely, I guess.

If you don't do any Google Apps Scripting,  like me, you won't know how to get there. Go here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

and click on the link "Start Scripting".  Choose "Create script for ...Blank Project".  You'll get an Untitled project window.  Save the project with a descriptive name (e.g. "Dummy Scripting Project").   It will appear among your Google Drive  (GD) files.  (I used the GD web interface for this.)  Reopen the script, access the menu item "Resources --> All Your Triggers"  and delete DriveEye triggers. Save and close the project.

Now wait.  In a few days, all the DriveEye error messages should cease.

HTH